# Dump a MySQL table to a CSV file and save it in a given location using Python script

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I used following python script to dump a MySQL table to a CSV file. But it was saved in the same folder which python script is saved. I want to save it in another folder. How can I do it? Thank you

```
print 'Writing database to csv file'

import MySQLdb
import csv
import time
import datetime
import os

currentDate=datetime.datetime.now().date()

user = ''
passwd = ''
host = ''
db = ''
table = ''

con = MySQLdb.connect(user=user, passwd=passwd, host=host, db=db)
cursor = con.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM %s;" % table
cursor.execute(query)

with open('Data on %s.csv' % currentDate ,'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        writer.writerow(row)

print 'Done'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
with open('/full/path/tofile/Data on %s.csv' % currentDate ,'w') as f:
```

This solves your problem X. But you have a problem Y. That is 'How do i efficiently, dump CSV data from mysql, without having to write a lot of code?'

Answer to problem Y is [SELECT INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html)